# SQL - No Nulls on Left Join

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have been working with a Chart control in a WinForms Application, and have had some trouble with plotting the correct points - i have tried a multitude of things including the DataManipulator.InsertEmptyPoints, to no avail.

So, i decided to improve my SQL Query - which has been done, but it is still not including 0/Null Values - but i'm having some trouble with my left join - it's not returning any Null Values.

Query:

```sql
SELECT FC_Name , count (Findings.Findings_ID) AS 'NumFindings'
FROM FindingCategories
     LEFT JOIN Findingsubcategories ON Findingsubcategories.FC_ID = FindingCategories.FC_ID
     LEFT JOIN Findings ON Findings.FSC_ID = Findingsubcategories.FSC_ID
     -- LEFT JOIN Audit ON Audit.Audit_ID = Findings.AU_ID
     -- WHERE Audit.Audit_ID = 932
     GROUP BY FC_Name
```

The output of the query

[image: Query with no Comment]

Now, when i remove my comments and include the two lines in the query

[image]

Where as i want it to be something like:

```
FC_Name    | NumFindings
Category         1
Category         6
Category         1
Category         0/Null
Category         0/Null
Category         0/Null
Category         0/Null
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try `LEFT JOIN Audit ON Audit.Audit_ID = Findings.AU_ID AND Audit.Audit_ID = 932` instead of using a separate WHERE?

Comment: Didnt change my result :/

Comment: @Krono, post your solution as an answer to this question. And then accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to deduce that one of my joins was redundant and didnt do anything, the solution:

```sql
SELECT FC_Name, COUNT(Findings.Findings_ID) AS 'NumFindings'
FROM FindingCategories
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Findingsubcategories ON Findingsubcategories.FC_ID = FindingCategories.FC_ID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Findings ON Findings.FSC_ID = Findingsubcategories.FSC_ID AND Findings.AU_ID = 932
 GROUP BY FC_Name
```

Comment: You solved it by changing from `LEFT JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which changes the result.  You could put those other joins back in and change them to outer joins and it would still work.  It's the `OUTER` that makes the difference.

Comment: @Corey, incorrect.

It wasnt **just** the join type, but my where statement as well.
I am currently attempting to make this query now work with previous year data.

Comment: @Corey The issue was because of the WHERE, which filtered the result after the join. However, putting the constraint on the join revealed the fact that the filtering must be done on `Findings`, so left-joining to Audit did nothing, and could be removed entirely

Comment: @Rob, any clue how i could perhaps make this query work with a data entry from a previous year? ( in a second statement )- i can currently do this by just doing Audit_ID-1, but previous year values will not always be -1 behind

Comment: @Krono If you have a `datetime` column, you could do it via `datediff`. Though I don't see how Audit_ID relates to a year.. and it probably shouldn't. What if there are two audits in a year, for some reason?

Comment: @Rob no datetime, just a "Year" column in a different table, and this is because different audits happen over different years, so its to compare the  amount of data across the two
i had done this before, but with a much more complex query that suffered from the same error as the one above

Comment: @Krono In that case it's a bit more complicated. You should probably open a new question showing your full schema, it's hard to do it via comments (plus SQL isn't exactly my strong suit ;) - you can get better answerers)